# Adding custom CSS to fastify-swagger

Tags: swagger-ui, fastify

I need to add some custom CSS to the fastify-swagger. My fastify-swagger version is: 3.5.0.

Now I did checked the fastify-swagger PR [#353](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-swagger/pull/351). However not able to figure out in the uiConfig .. how to pass the custom css.

Suppose I have a simple css file as MyCSS.scss:

```
.introduction {
    .summary {
        text-shadow: 0in;
    }
}

.code { 
    background-color: gray; 
    color: black; 
}
```

My swagger config looks like:

```
const swaggerConfig = {
    swagger: {
      info: {
        title: 'My swagger',
        description: `something`,
        version: '2.0.0'
      },
      externalDocs: {
        url: 'https://swagger.io',
        description: 'Find more info here'
      },
      schemes: [`${schema}`],
      consumes: ['application/json'],
      produces: ['application/json'],
      tags: [
        { name: 'tag1', description: 'desc1' },
        { name: 'tag2', description: 'desc2' },
      ],
      securityDefinitions: {
        Authorization_Token: {
            type: 'apiKey',
            name: 'Authorization',
            in: 'header'
        },
        User_Token: {
            type: 'apiKey',
            name: 'X-User-token',
            in: 'header'
        }
      }
    },
    exposeRoute: true,
    routePrefix: `${constants.EXTERNAL_PATH}/api-docs`
};
fastify.register(require('fastify-swagger'), swaggerConfig);
```

The UI config doc says something like this (only literal value):
[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you tried https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6346 ?

Comment: I did not get it properly. So what would be the flow? I need to create a fastify plugin or fastify-swagger plugin? Then in that plugin, I need to use the swagger-ui plugin as pointed here https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/customization/plugin-api/ ?